# при распаковке архива вместо пустых папок создаются пустые файлы без разширения

Tags: java

при распаковке архива вместо пустых папок создаются пустые файлы без разширения

```
    String filename = "C:/крис280917.rar";
    File f = new File(filename);
    Archive a = null;
    try {
        a = new Archive(new FileVolumeManager(f));
    } catch (RarException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (a != null) {
        a.getMainHeader().print();
        FileHeader fh = a.nextFileHeader();
            while (fh != null) {
                try {
                    String value = fh.getFileNameW().trim();
                    File out = new File("C:/unrar/" + value);
                    System.out.println(out.getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println(out.isDirectory());
                    File parent = out.getParentFile();
                    if(!parent.exists() && !parent.mkdirs()) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't create dir: " + parent);
                    }
                    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);
                    a.extractFile(fh, os);
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                } catch (RarException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                fh = a.nextFileHeader();
            }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
File out = new File("C:/unrar/" + value).mkdirs();
```

Comment: это сделает вообще все папками)